# Need a fix for MKDIR

Tags: file-management, user-folders, mkdir

I've been using OmniGraffle as a drawing tool for a textbook I'm writing.
Up to today I've drawn the drawing, saved it as a graffle.
I then, export the same graffle drawing as a png, as per my publisher's requirements.(With NO problems)

This morning for some reason, I now get the following message when I go to export the drawing as a png.

"
The document “9.1 Simplify Fract Ex.12.graffle” could not be exported as “9.1 Simplify Fract Ex.12.png”. mkdir: /Users/condor2892/Desktop/Wiley Drawings/Ch7: Operation not permitted
"

1./What does it mean and is it fixable?
2./How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

mkdir tries to create a folder/directory (MaKe a DIRectory). Either the application you are using does not have rights to create the directory in that place, or the application mistakenly believes that it doesn't have these rights. The following options all have a good chance of fixing the issue:

1. Create the directory yourself.
2. Export the drawing to a different folder.
3. Run the application as administrator.

Comment: Thanks Peter!
Upon further investigation, it's related to the new Mac security update of the 16th and OmniGraffle, which uses php. How would I create a directory, if I chose that option.

Comment: You could use mkdir in combination with sudo, or if that's too complicated: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-new-folder-in-mac-os-x-lion.html